# Multiple FlipClocks Not Formatting Correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to get multiple flipclocks to work inside multiple repeaters in ASP.NET/c#.  I can get the multiple clocks to display, but the formatting is all wrong.

[image]

I've seen code on stackoverflow where they say all you need to do is add the flipclock.js library, the flipclock.css and below code:

```
<div id="currentClock" class="clock-1" data-countdown="2015/07/15 17:12:20" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
```

And you need to add the following jQuery so that it can populate all of the clock-1 objects:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var clocks = [];

        $('.clock-1').each(function() {
            var clock = $(this),
                date = (new Date(clock.data('countdown')).getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;

            clock.FlipClock(date, {
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                countdown: true
            });

            clocks.push(clock);
        });
    });
```

I also found this code on the web and when I run it, it looks/works great!  I could use this code, but I don't know how I would populate the 'date' variable below with something like '<%#Eval("ClosingDate") %>'.

```
<div id="divClickBuilder1" class="clock-1" style="margin-left: 50px; "></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="compiled/flipclock.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">body .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn, body .flip-clock-small-wrapper1 ul li a div div.inn { color: #CCCCCC; background-color: #0095cc !important; } body .flip-clock-dot, body .flip-clock-small-wrapper .flip-clock-dot { background: #323434; } body .flip-clock-wrapper .flip-clock-meridium a, body .flip-clock-small-wrapper .flip-clock-meridium a { color: #323434; }</style>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        FlipClock.Lang.Custom = { days:'Days', hours:'Hours', minutes:'Minutes', seconds:'Seconds' };
        var opts = {
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
            countdown: true,
            language: 'English'
        };  
        var date = new Date(2019, 7, 30);
        var now = new Date();
        var diff = (date.getTime() / 1000) - (now.getTime() / 1000);

        $('.clock1').FlipClock(diff, opts);
    });
</script>
```

---

[image]

I want to use the jQuery method because it seems so much cleaner to create these clocks such as:

```
<div id="currentClock" runat="server" class="clock-1" data-countdown='<%#Eval("ClosingDate") %>' style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
```

I have the same 'style' tag, CSS and JS library in this code as I do the one above that works/looks fine.  However, instead of having the DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES & SECONDS with colons inbetween and the clock flipping correctly, I get a format that looks like:  - 1 8 1 3 1 - 1 : 9 ? : 1 5 : - 8 and the clock **NOT** flipping.

How do I set the appropriate options to make these clock(s) look/work correctly?